# How do GroupBox's and RadioButton's work together?

Tags: c#

Could anyone explain me how the compiler knows to perform appropriate method when we select RadioButtons in this example ?

Comment: I guess this is what the **downvoters** like best (of course not me included:)

Comment: I know you don't have rights to include images...then type out the code. Maybe it will help you understand it along the way

Comment: I'd probably check the book first...

Comment: Fixed you question to show the images you included

Comment: Next time you post a question, make sure you include only the revelant parts and type (copy/paste) it directly here. As the question stand now it's kind of a pain to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure what you're asking. I *think* you're asking how the system knows that it should execute the `iconType_CheckChanged` method when one of the icon radio buttons is clicked, and how it knows that, for example, the `asteriskRadioButton` changed.

The answer is in two parts. First, in creating the program in Windows Forms, you hooked up the CheckChanged event handler for each of the radio buttons. So the `asteriskRadioButton` CheckChanged method contains the value `iconType_CheckChanged`. That information is added to the partial class that you don't usually see. It's in your Form.Designer.cs file in the `InitializeComponent` method. It looks something like:

```
this.asteriskRadioButton.CheckChanged += iconType_CheckChanged
```

You don't typically see the Form.Designer.cs file. To view it, expand the form node in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer and you'll see the file listed:

[image: show designer code]

The second part of the answer is that when you click the radio button (or when some code changes the state of the radio button), the underlying control machinery calls `iconType_CheckChanged`, passing a reference to the control that triggered the event in the `Sender` argument.